# How often should I feed my juvenile discus fish to grow their full potential

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium, cichlid

I have juvenile discus fish(2.5" to 3") and based on my online research it is said by many that three to four feedings in a day with wide variety of foods will help them grow healthy & to full potential.

Currently I'm following below feeding routing, (6 hours split in a day)

- Day Feedings **07:30AM** & **02:00PM**
- Night Feedings **08:00PM** &    **02:00AM**

1) Can someone suggest if this is a good feeding schedule & can i
    stick with it or any changes recommended?

2) Also, with my current feeding schedule I have been noticing that 1/4th of the food fed at **02:00AM** is left uneaten at the bottom of the tank. I'm not sure if its right time to feed or i should skip this feeding schedule.

Appreciate any additional suggestions on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my experience having a short time of taking care of a discus cichlid is I used to feed them at least 3 times a day with a Beefheart since they are around 2-3". After they eat the Beefheart, I will clean it up to avoid rotten food inside the tank and maintain the water quality. I don't rely on my filter. I am using a DIY filtration. I've seen them grow within 3-7months around 3-4" but I sell them to a friend because I fell in love with the Cichlids of Lake Tanganyika.

The most important thing I learned from doing a research before I bought this Discus is the water quality. You need to use a high quality of water since I live in South East Asia, there are a lot of us selling a gallon of water that used people for drinking, that is the water that I used for my discus tank.

To maintain a high quality of water, I do a water change at least 4-5 times a week with 10-15% water change but it is up to you if how do you maintain but on my side, I was kinda OC and I want to maintain a high-quality water and a clearer view of my tank with the Discus.